# Parse and convert a complex string to a python dictionary

Tags: python

I have got a output from a code written in C language in a of a old network switch and and store it to a txt file. the output is like

```
 Fan 1
   Description: Fan Tray 1, Left Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   Model: 06MY5N
   SN: CN06MY5N282989BJ0987
   RPM: 10031
   Speed: 52%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 3
   Description: Fan Tray 2, Left Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   Model: 06MY5N
   SN: CN06MY5N282989BJ0983
   RPM: 10031
   Speed: 52%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 2
   Description: Fan Tray 1, Right Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   Model: 06MY5N
   SN: CN06MY5N282989BJ0987
   RPM: 10031
   Speed: 52%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 5
   Description: Fan Tray 3, Left Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   Model: 06MY5N
   SN: CN06MY5N282989BJ0988
   RPM: 10240
   Speed: 53%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 4
   Description: Fan Tray 2, Right Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   Model: 06MY5N
   SN: CN06MY5N282989BJ0983
   RPM: 10031
   Speed: 52%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 7
   Description: PSU-1 Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   RPM: 10704
   Speed: 59%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 6
   Description: Fan Tray 3, Right Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   Model: 06MY5N
   SN: CN06MY5N282989BJ0988
   RPM: 10031
   Speed: 52%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
 Fan 8
   Description: PSU-2 Fan
   State: Present
   Status: Running
   RPM: 10736
   Speed: 59%
   Airflow: Front-to-Back
```

Now I have to parse it in a python dictionary from this file. The dictionary would look like

```
{"Fan 1": {"Description": "Fan Tray 1, Left Fan" , "State": "Present", ....}, "Fan 3": {"Description": "Fan Tray 1, Left Fan" , "State": "Present", ....}, ..., "Fan 8": {"Description": "Fan Tray 1, Left Fan" , "State": "Present", ....}
```

How can I made this? I am a new bee in python. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to do a little research, stack overflow is not a code writing service, that said, start with using https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-find/

Comment: What have you tried? If you post your code then perhaps we can help or give some advice.

Comment: post what code you have tried or what errors you got. this isnt a code writting service.

Comment: “There are many things that seem impossible only so long as one does not attempt them.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('text.txt','r') as fin:
    lines=[l.strip('\n') for l in fin.readlines()]
    
dic={}
for line in lines:
    if not line.startswith('   '):
        key=line.strip()
        dic[key]={}
    else:
        k,v=line.strip().split(': ')
        dic[key].update({k:v})
```

**Output:**

```
{'Fan 1': {'Description': 'Fan Tray 1, Left Fan',
  'State': 'Present',
  'Status': 'Running',
  'Model': '06MY5N',
  'SN': 'CN06MY5N282989BJ0987',
  'RPM': '10031',
  'Speed': '52%',
  'Airflow': 'Front-to-Back'},...}
```